# Android FileInputStream exception file not found

Tags: java, android, tar

I'm trying to untar a tar with [jtar](https://github.com/kamranzafar/jtar) and I'm getting

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: Download/Data.tar (No such file or directory)

I'm not using an emulator, it's directly on my phone.

The file does exist in my android's downloads folder (even before the app starts).

I have all the permissions to read/write.

```
File tarFile = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "Data.tar");
        File destFolder = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + "/My Data/");
        if(!destFolder.exists())
        {
            // Make it, if it doesn't exit
            destFolder.mkdirs();
        }else{
            //TODO
            //delete the folder contents
        }


        // Create a TarInputStream
        try {
            TarInputStream tis = new TarInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(tarFile)));
            TarEntry entry;

            while ((entry = tis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                int count;
                byte data[] = new byte[2048];
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destFolder + "/" + entry.getName());
                BufferedOutputStream dest = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

                while ((count = tis.read(data)) != -1) {
                    dest.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                dest.flush();
                dest.close();
            }

            tis.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast2.show();
            Log.e("TAG", "error", e);
        }
```

Logcat says the error is on the first line after the try

**EDIT:**  for some reason it doesn't even create the /My Data/ folder even though it does go to `destFolder.mkdirs();` when I'm debugging. not sure how it relates

**EDIT 2:**  I discovered that the `tarFile.exists()` and `tarFile.canRead()` says false, I tried to put an explicit path `"storage/emulated/0/Download/Data.tar"` AND IT WORKS, it exists and readable.

Is there any danger leaving it like this? would some phones have a different `...emullated/X/...` number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I SOLVED IT!

`File tarFile = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "Data.tar");`

will try to get a relative path from your app, even if you will write `tarFile.getAbsolutePath()`.

The solution?
`File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "Data.tar");`

Comment: not that the untar part of the code even works :/
but now I feel free again after 4(?) hours

Answer (score 0):

If the android version of your device is larger than 6.0, only declare permissions request in AndroidManifest xml is not enough. You should also **explicitly** request before any operations which need permission.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // Permission is not granted
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
    } else {
        // No explanation needed; request the permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[] {
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            },
            MY_PERMISSIONS_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did it at the start of the activity and just to make sure I used your code (+read permission) to check again, and I had all the permissions

Comment: @Ron create folder/file need 'write' permission

Comment: yeah but reading the data.tar needs also read premission. and i just checked and using an explicit path "/storage/emulated/0/Download/Data.tar DOES find the file and it says it exists and readable